# why do extensive games with perfect information have at least one nash equilibrium?

Tags: self-learning, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I would argue that every finite extensive game with perfect information has a subgame perfect equilibrium [1] and every subgame perfect equilibrium is also a nash equilibrium, thus every finite extensive game with perfect information has a nash equilibrium. Is that explanation correct?

Osborne M.J. An Introduction to Game Theory, P. 171

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thanks! Also I did not find a proof for the proposition in the book. Is there a quick explanation why every finite extensive game with perfect information has a subgame perfect equilibrium?

Comment: Intuitively, it is fairly clear that backward induction gives you a Nash equilibrium, but writing things up rigorously becomes notationally messy.